# Does VSO support local build agent?

Tags: azure-devops

The new TFS Build does not seem to have an option to target the Build to a local build controller, is this correct?

I can only see "Hosted" or "Default" in the General tab.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/overview

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://techtwaddle.net/2015/07/07/setting-up-an-on-premise-build-agent-with-visual-studio-online/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new pool
2. Create a new queue
3. Download and configure the agent

More details can be found on [Deploy an agent to build Windows and Azure apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/agents/windows)